# Xaudio2 XAPO Effects

Tags: xna, audio

I've been working with XAudio2. After looking at the samples, example code, and sparse documentation available from Microsoft and the MSDN, I've found that there aren't any easy-to-find resources on creating and using XAPO effects, nor any XAPO effects produced by third parties that I can download and/or buy.

What it looks like is that if I create an app that uses XAPO effects, I'll have to create them all myself because there's no community of existing applications like there is with technologies like Apple's AU or Steinberg's VST. Is this true, or are there others using XAudio2 and XAPO and I just haven't found them?

Is there a place to ask programmer-support-related questions about XAudio2 and related technologies (or is this the best destination)? The best I've found so far are the XNA forums, which are game-specific and sparsely populated in the audio area.

Answer (score 1):

XAPO is a rather new technology and as such not widely supported (yet). So, yes, you have to create most of your effects yourself, however it shouldn’t be too hard to port/convert the older DirectSound SFX’ (I forgot the name of that technology and if it even was related to DirectSound…).

The [AppBuh DirectX > Audio/XACT forum](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/33.aspx) and the [DirectX mailing list](http://discussms.hosting.lsoft.com/SCRIPTS/WA-MSD.EXE?A0=DIRECTXDEV) seems to be the places to ask questions about XAudio2, even though both are rather low frequency but will get you [“access” to the devs of it](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/8716.aspx) :)